# Why deadlock occurs?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, transactions, deadlock, isolation-level

I use a small transaction which consists of two simple queries: select and update:

```
SELECT * FROM XYZ WHERE ABC = DEF
```

and

```
UPDATE XYZ SET ABC = 123
WHERE ABC = DEF
```

It is quite often situation when the transaction is started by two threads, and depending on Isolation Level deadlock occurs (RepeatableRead, Serialization). Both transactions try to read and update exactly the same row.
I'm wondering why it is happening. What is the order of queries which leads to deadlock? I've read a bit about lock (shared, exclusive) and how long locks last for each isolation level, but I still don't fully understand...

I've even prepared a simple test which always result in deadlock. I've looked at results of the test in SSMS and SQL Server Profiler. I started first query and then immediately the second.

First query:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SELECT ...
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:04'
UPDATE ...
COMMIT
```

Second query:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SELECT ...
UPDATE ...
COMMIT
```

Now I'm not able to show you detailed logs, but it looks less or more like this (I've very likely missed Lock:deadlock etc. somewhere):

```
(1) SQL:BatchStarting: First query
(2) SQL:BatchStarting: Second query
(3) Lock:timeout for second query
(4) Lock:timeout for first query
(5) Deadlock graph
```

If I understand locks well, in (1) first query takes a shared lock (to execute SELECT), then goes to sleep and keeps the shared lock until the end of transaction. In (2) second query also takes shared lock (SELECT) but cannot take exclusive lock (UPDATE) while there are shared locks on the same row, which results in Lock:timeout. But I can't explain why timeout for second query occurs. Probably I don't understand the whole process well. Can anybody give a good explanation?

I haven't noticed deadlocks using ReadCommitted but I'm afraid they may occur. 
What solution do you recommend?

Comment: Not what you're asking, but why are you selecting first, then updating? In other words, why don't you use a transaction consisting of only the update statement?

Comment: i simplified my problem. first I check last modification date and then depending on the value do something and then change the date. in this transaction there are more queries but these above makes problems with deadlocks. I tried to understand fully what is the reason, because I have never before heard about locks and information found in inter]net doesn't satisfy me enough :) in my case dirty reads are not a problem so I decided to choose read uncommitted. I use realizable just to see what will happen, a kind of experiment :)

Comment: there should be serializable instead of realizable :) I forgot to say I'm using c#, but it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A deadlock occurs when two or more tasks permanently block each other by each task having a lock on a resource which the other tasks are trying to lock

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177433.aspx

Comment: Still how can this happen if the isolation level is SERIALIZABLE ?!

Comment: Check the following link for better descriptions of transaction levels, Muhammad http://www.brentozar.com/isolation-levels-sql-server/

Answer (score 3):

"But I can't explain why timeout for second query occurs."

Because the first query holds shared lock. Then the update in the first query also tries to get the exclusive lock, which makes him sleep. So the first and second query are both sleeping waiting for the other to wake up - and this is a deadlock which results in timeout :-)

In mysql it works better - the deadlock is detected immediatelly and one of the transactions is rolled back (you need not to wait for timeout :-)).

Also, in mysql, you can do the following to **prevent deadlock**:

```
select ... for update
```

which will put a write-lock (i.e. exclusive lock) just from the beginning of the transaction, and this way you avoid the deadlock situation! Perhaps you can do something similar in your database engine.

Comment: I meant timeout for first query (but it's the second timeout). My mistake. After David's post everything is clear :) But thanks for answer.

Comment: it is the same reason for both - the reason is the deadlock. Try to find out if you can do the prevention I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

For MSSQL there is a mechanism to prevent deadlocks. What you need here is called the `WITH NOLOCK` hint.

In 99.99% of the cases of `SELECT` statements it's usable and there is no need to bundle the SELECT with the UPDATE. There is also no need to put a SELECT into a transaction. The only exception is when dirty reads are not allowed.

Changing your queries to this form would solve all your issues:

```
SELECT ...
FROM yourtable WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE ...

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
BEGIN TRANSACTION
UPDATE ...
COMMIT
```

Comment: Changing all queries using `WITH (NOLOCK)` ?

Answer (score 1):

It has been a long time since I last dealt with this, but I believe that the select statement creates a read-lock, which only prevents the data to be changed -- hence multiple queries can hold and share a read-lock on the same data.   The shared-read-lock is for read consistency, that is if you multiple times in your transaction reads the same row, then read-consistency should mean that you should always get the same result.

The update statement requires an exclusive lock, and hence the update statement have to wait for the read-lock to be released.

None of the two transactions will release the locks, so the transactions fails.

Different databases implementations have different strategies for how to deal with this, with Sybase and MS-SQL-servers using lock escalation with timeout (escalate from read-to-write-lock) -- Oracle I believe (at some point) implemented read consistency though use of the roll-back-log,  where MySQL have yet a different strategy.

Comment: It is possible when dealing with deadlock and lock escalation in SQL Server to solve some lock contention issues with the use of isolation levels. However, that can introduce it's own set of issues with data inaccuracy.

Kendra little drew a little cartoon for comparison here: http://www.littlekendra.com/2011/02/08/isoposter/

MSDN Isolation level artickle is here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213034(v=sql.80).aspx